# Using list with a Defined Class Method in Python

Tags: python

I have a requirement below but I am getting some error:

Write a separate Privileges class. The class should have one attribute, privileges, that stores a list of strings.Move the show_privileges() method to this class. Make a Privileges instance as an attribute in the Admin class. Create a new instance of Admin and use your method to show its privileges.

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        """Initiating attributes of user class"""
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.login_attempts = 1

    def describe_user(self):
        """Print summary of the user info"""
        print(f"User's info is {self.first_name}  {self.last_name}")

    def greet_user(self):
        """ Method greets user"""
        print(f"Goodday, {self.first_name} {self.last_name}!")

    def increment_login_attempts(self, login):
        """Method increments login attempts"""
        self.login_attempts += login
        print(f"This user  has {self.login_attempts} login attempts")

    def reset_login_attempts(self):
        """Method resets login attempts"""
        self.login_attempts = 0

class Privileges:

    def __init__(self, privileges):
        """ Shows admin privileges"""
        self.privileges = privileges

    def show_privileges(self):
        """Lists admin privileges"""
        print(f"This user {','' '.join(self.privileges)}")

class Admin(User):
    """ Represents Admin privileges of a user"""
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, privileges):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name)
        self.privileges = Privileges()


my_Admin_user = Admin('john', 'olode', ["Can Add Post", "Can Delete Post", "Can Ban User"])
my_Admin_user.describe_user()
my_Admin_user.greet_user()
my_Admin_user.Privileges.show_privileges()
```

Error Below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "userPrivilegeClass.py", line 43, in <module>
    my_Admin_user = Admin('john', 'olode', ["Can Add Post", "Can Delete Post", "Can Ban User"])
  File "userPrivilegeClass.py", line 39, in __init__
    self.privileges = Privileges()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'privileges'
```

Would appreciate any help.
FYI, I am very new to python (about a month), please bear with me whuile you dumb it down for me.. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Privileges` accepts one argument (`priveleges`) upon instantiation. You didn't supply one on this line in your `Admin` class:

```
self.privileges = Privileges()
```

I suspect you want to change that line to:

```
self.privileges = Privileges(privileges)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your really close the only thing your missing is giving `Permissions` the reuqired position arg

```
...
class Admin(User):
    """ Represents Admin privileges of a user"""
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, privileges):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name)
        self.privileges = Privileges(privileges) # Here we pass the privileges to the `__init__` method

...
```